# Memory leak with linkedHashMap

Tags: java, memory-leaks

I have a memory leak in my web application, this memory leak due to linkedHashMap and WebappClassLoader.
 So I must know in my code if there is something make this memory leak. Unfortunately, I don't notice the reason for this memory leak.
  I search on google to know the possibility of having a memory leak with linkedHashMap but I don't have a solution.

 All I need to know more information about this case of this memory leak, how can I resolve it and the possibility of having a memory leak in my case.

Comment: "memory leak due to linkedHashMap"? How did you come to know?

Comment: I use IBM head analyzer

Answer (score 0):

Generally, memory leaks happen when references to objects are not garbage collected. Can you post some of your code related to `LinkedHashMap`? You can use `JVisual` - shipped in the SDK - to find the class causing memory leak.

In `WebappClassLoader`, `ThreadLocal` is notorious for memory leaks.